# Can we lose kafka message in case of poweroff?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a theoretical question about how Kafka process fails.
Suppose we have only 1 partition and 2 consumers. I know it's unlikely to have such situation, but it's for example and I really want to understand it better. I have enabled autocommit and a little commit interval.

The partition is:

```
P: M1, M2, M3
```

where M1, M2 and M3 are messages with their offsets (1, 2, 3).

Suppose the following:

```
T1: M1, M2 - failed
T2: M3
```

which means that worker (thread) 1 got M1 and successfully processed it, but it failed on processing M2. For example, poweroff or some hardware problem. But it has committed offset 2 before failing (BTW – is this possible?). And thread 2 got M3, successfully processed it and committed offset of 3.

In a result we have lost M2 message.
The question – is this possible? Sorry in advance if the question is a kind of obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [this](https://sookocheff.com/post/kafka/kafka-in-a-nutshell/) excellent article:

> Before beginning the discussion on consistency and availability, keep
>   in mind that these guarantees hold as long as you are producing to one
>   partition and consuming from one partition. **All guarantees are off
>   if you are reading from the same partition using two consumers or
>   writing to the same partition using two producers.**

Therefore, with two consumers, you can't expect to access the message that you lost during processing. However, if you stick with one consumer and use "at least once message delivery" mode, then:

> For at least
>   once delivery, the consumer reads data from a partition, processes the
>   message, and then commits the offset of the message it has processed.
>   I**n this case, the consumer could crash between processing the message
>   and committing the offset and when the consumer restarts it will
>   process the message again.** This leads to duplicate messages in
>   downstream systems but no data loss.

Comment: Awesome article! "If the consumer crashes between committing the offset and processing the message it will restart from the next offset without ever having processed the message. This would lead to potentially undesirable message loss." – exactly what I was speaking about. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, do you know is it a good idea to have multiple workers (threads) when using KafkaConsumer? What happens when each thread is calling 'poll(100)' and then 'commitSync()' on the same topic?

Comment: @tmn4jq We are using C++ client (edenhill/librdkafka), so I am not familiar with the details of Java API. However, I would strongly advise to increase the number of partitions and have one consumer per partition - it gave us the best results. You can of course have a single KafkaConsumer and multiple worker threads that process received messages, but in that case you have to take care about order of commited messages and synchronization, which Kafka already gives you out of the box.

Comment: @tmn4jq Btw, this may be helpful: http://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/05/29/create-multi-threaded-apache-kafka-consumer/

Answer (score 1):

Kafka guarantees message delivery at least once. But you will never lose messages.

The scenario you said can never happen. It cannot commit offset unless it read the message. You have turned on the auto commit. That just says that you will commit the offset for every regular interval of time. It doesn't mean that the offset will move forward without reading the message. Kafka guarantees that.

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#semantics

Comment: I am speaking about external probmels. Suppose a situation when consumer took a message from a partition and then commit happened. Just the inteval passed. And then BAM! Poweroff and consumer dies. Is the message lost? Because commit is done, because message was fetched from the log. But it wasn't successfully processed.

Comment: But 'at least once' strategy looks good and yes – it will prevent such situations. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If you think such scenario is quite possible, then you have to do a manual commit. Commit only after you have processed the message.